# 80's sci-fi book series: space travelers can transform into any other creature, are chased by "Val's" robots

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a lot of books in the 1980's and some I borrowed from friends. I would like to find this series if anyone can figure out what it was.

The story started out with a person or several persons escaping in a large ship from certain doom.  They traveled across the galaxy searching for something that was spread out across 5 planets.  They could transform their body mass to become any other being or creature as long as it had the same or less mass.

They were chased across the galaxy by robots called "Val's" or something like that. Eventually they found the last clue on Earth. It was a secret kept by native Indians or air base or something like that.  Again my memory is fuzzy on the details.

If I recall this was either a 3 book series or 5 book series.

Comment: Confirmation of duplicate in comment by OP below.

Comment: ^ comment which has been deleted, unfortunately :-/

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are thinking of Jack Chalkers 'Rings of the Master' Series. The question has been answered before ... try here - [Series of sci-fi novels: sisters turned into cow like aliens, mother ship full of humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82887/series-of-sci-fi-novels-sisters-turned-into-cow-like-aliens-mother-ship-full-o/82905#82905)

Comment: Val's are the name that Jack L Chalker gave to the cyborgs in the Rings of the Master series

Comment: Cant wait to get and re-read...